# CSS negation pseudo class not working

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I pay be asking too much of this negation pseudo.

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

In CSS, I have:

```
.item:hover .item:not(.item:hover) {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

I hoped that this would cause all the div.items to change opacity when I hover one, with the exception of the one I am hovering.  But, it doesn't.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use-case I'd suggest:

```
div:hover div.item {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

div:hover div.item:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pvgEs/).

The problem is that your selector is looking for element with the class `item`, that is not hovered, within another element of the same class. Your posted CSS shows that the parent element does not have a class, and so the selector can never match.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)